# Can I create an app for Google Play Store in C++?

Tags: google-play

I need to know whether I can create an app for Google Play Store in C++, or whether I have to use Java.

I don't have a JDK, so if I can use C++, then that would make things easier and cheaper.

Comment: You may be able to write parts of the application in C++ but you do have to use JDK for other parts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's what it is.  Call me a troll if you like.

Comment: It's a legit question ...

Comment: Tags `store` and `playback`seems wrong. Why not use the `google-play` tag

Comment: You probably need some JVM bytecode for Android. You could produce it with a non Java compiler (perhaps Scala, or Clojure, ...). BTW, you might install Linux on your PC, since it is quite developer friendly (and installing some Android SDK is then quite easy)

Comment: Check for "Qt for android" (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html) maybe this is what you need. But i don't know is qt apps acceptable on google play store

Comment: @johngull See: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digia.Qt5Intro So from that I am assuming it is supported (I actually remembered this since I downloaded that a while back on an Android Tablet)

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the Qt library at http://www.qt.io/

From the [Tools and Versions](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-5.5.0-tools-and-versions) page for the latest version (5.5) it states:

> Android NDK   r10c    r10c    r10c
>
> Android SDK   r24.0.2 r24.0.2 r24.0.2

And in the Play Store there are a few Qt example applications:

- [Introduction to Qt 5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digia.Qt5Intro)
- [Qt 5 Everywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digia.Qt5Everywhere)

You can download an open source version of Qt from [here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

There are also some steps on the [Getting Started with Qt for Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) documents page.

PS:
*I have not attempted to use Qt for Mobile (Android, Win Phone, iPhone) development but I am planning to test this sometime this year.*

Edit: I see you do need the Android SDK, NDK and Java JDK but at least you don't need to code in Java if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone for you quick replies!

Based on your answers, it looks like it's time to give me laptop new life so I can use pure Java.

Thanks again!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.